# NestJs installation on iisnode and Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: node.js, nestjs, iis-8, iisnode

When I try to install NestJs application on IIS-server (with iisnode installed) I always just encounter issue which says
"...Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3450.." (see below)
And, as you can see from the console.log (see below), the NestJs application is first fully initialized and launched, but then comes always the port already in use issue. And it persists no matter how many different ports I try. I have also tried to restart iisnode.exe and killed the process and the port but it does not help. Anyone any experience with this and found the solution?

> node dist/main

```
[32m[Nest] 36096   - [39m09/01/2020, 1:43:54 PM   [33m[NestFactory] [39m[32mStarting Nest application...[39m
[32m[Nest] 36096   - [39m09/01/2020, 1:43:54 PM   [33m[InstanceLoader] [39m[32mConfigHostModule dependencies initialized[39m[33m +34ms[39m
[32m[Nest] 36096   - [39m09/01/2020, 1:43:54 PM   [33m[InstanceLoader] [39m[32mAppModule dependencies initialized[39m[33m +0ms[39m
[32m[Nest] 36096   - [39m09/01/2020, 1:43:54 PM   [33m[InstanceLoader] [39m[32mConfigModule dependencies initialized[39m[33m +1ms[39m
hello from NestJs app
[32m[Nest] 36096   - [39m09/01/2020, 1:43:54 PM   [33m[RoutesResolver] [39m[32mAppController {}:[39m[33m +13ms[39m
[32m[Nest] 36096   - [39m09/01/2020, 1:43:54 PM   [33m[RouterExplorer] [39m[32mMapped {, GET} route[39m[33m +4ms[39m
[32m[Nest] 36096   - [39m09/01/2020, 1:43:54 PM   [33m[RoutesResolver] [39m[32mItemsController {/items}:[39m[33m +0ms[39m
[32m[Nest] 36096   - [39m09/01/2020, 1:43:54 PM   [33m[RouterExplorer] [39m[32mMapped {/items, GET} route[39m[33m +1ms[39m
[32m[Nest] 36096   - [39m09/01/2020, 1:43:54 PM   [33m[RouterExplorer] [39m[32mMapped {/items/:id, GET} route[39m[33m +2ms[39m
[32m[Nest] 36096   - [39m09/01/2020, 1:43:54 PM   [33m[RouterExplorer] [39m[32mMapped {/items, POST} route[39m[33m +1ms[39m
[32m[Nest] 36096   - [39m09/01/2020, 1:43:54 PM   [33m[RoutesResolver] [39m[32mShoppingCartController {/shopping-cart}:[39m[33m +1ms[39m
[32m[Nest] 36096   - [39m09/01/2020, 1:43:54 PM   [33m[RouterExplorer] [39m[32mMapped {/shopping-cart, POST} route[39m[33m +0ms[39m
[32m[Nest] 36096   - [39m09/01/2020, 1:43:54 PM   [33m[NestApplication] [39m[32mNest application successfully started[39m[33m +4ms[39m
App is running in port: 61302
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::61302
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1447:7)
    at ExpressAdapter.listen (C:\...\node_modules\@nestjs\platform-express\adapters\express-adapter.js:45:32)
    at NestApplication.listen (C:\...\node_modules\@nestjs\core\nest-application.js:146:26)
    at async bootstrap (C:\...\dist\main.js:8:9)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1340:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 61302
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nest-restaurant-api@0.0.1 start:prod: `node dist/main`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nest-restaurant-api@0.0.1 start:prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\...\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-01T12_43_54_285Z-debug.log
```

In iisnode server error log I can also find the following:
*(this proved to be logged in previous day - and not to be seen anymore in the logs. So, this iisnode log message may not be relevant for the issue at all)*

```
(node:45472) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(node:45472) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [ERR_SOCKET_BAD_PORT]: options.port should be >= 0 and < 65536. Received NaN.
    at validatePort (internal/validators.js:182:11)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1439:5)
    at ExpressAdapter.listen (C:\...\node_modules\@nestjs\platform-express\adapters\express-adapter.js:45:32)
    at NestApplication.listen (C:\...\node_modules\@nestjs\core\nest-application.js:146:26)
    at async bootstrap (C:\...\dist\main.js:7:5)
(node:45472) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:45472) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

In addition here is the /dist/main.js file in its present form (I have added those try / catch -statements).

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const core_1 = require("@nestjs/core");
const app_module_1 = require("./app.module");
async function bootstrap() {
    try {
        const app = await core_1.NestFactory.create(app_module_1.AppModule);
        await app.listen(parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 8080)
        .catch((e) => {
            console.error(e);
            process.exit(1);
        });
        console.log('App is running in port: ' + process.env.PORT);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("Error message: " + error);
    }
}
bootstrap().catch(e => { 
    console.error(e);
});
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

Comment: This is really an strange question. You can try to use the dos command to see which process is occupying port 61302, then kill the process and use nodejs run to start application.     Netstat –aon|findstr “61302”    Taskkill /pid  “process id”

Comment: I totally agree that my question is strange! - but I had to made it. The issue I face takes place in shared remote iis-server where I do not have a direct access to dos command line. My host provider, however, already did the killing of process by my request, but the issue persist for some strange reason, and if change the port number to any other, the same issue is there always. Note, however, that I do not have this issue with port in my local pc's development environment. Everything works there just fine.

Comment: Just for the sake of testing, I installed iisnode on my local pc (Win 10 / IIS 10). And I then deployed the very same NestJs application on my local IIS and it works fine, no port already in use issue, or any other issue for that matter. The installed version is:
iisnode version is 0.2.21, (node version is 13.10.1).

Comment: Who is your remote server provider? Some programs set by the server provider may occupy this port to monitor the server. You can check information about their server.

Comment: Today, I finally got intuition what is the cause of the issue - and after couple of simple tests I came to the insight that there must be an error in node.js path-settings as they must be defined in Plesk control panel. The difficulty was that there was no such error message which could have pointed to the real cause of the issue (such like "iisnode cannot find the start file for the application"). The error "port already at use" really did not help much at all. After setting a correct path, the app started to work as expected (both as root installation and  sub-folder installation).

Comment: So, thank you Bruce anyway for your caring - my host provider is M6 and, as can be figured out, they have nothing to do actually with the issue. IISnode is not giving always useful error messages. And it can therefore become a real burden to find one's way to the not so obvious cause.

Comment: I am glad that your problem has been solved. If you can, please post a solution and mark it to help those who may have the same proble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Bruce Zhang in his comment I will post the solution I found by myself.

So, the cause of the error was quite silly indeed.

1.) Using Plesk controlling panel (in IIS-server), irrespective of whether the NestJs application is deployed to site root or sub folder (like the default dist folder ), it is essential to get path settings to project to refer correctly:

[image]

Now, in the image above, path settings to project are correct when deployed to sub folder (i.e. default build folder dist). My error was that path reference for the Application Startup File was "/dist/main.js" as it should be just main.js.

After this simple correction app started normally with default IIS-port (port 80 and for SSL-protected connection 443). The main.ts -file does not have to anything else than just the following with the IIS default port fetched automatically via process.env.PORT:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    await app.listen(process.env.PORT);
}

bootstrap();
```

2.) The second simple thing that must be correctly configured is web.config (and this was originally correct in my case):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="dist/main.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    
    <iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"> 
    </iisnode> 
    
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="nestjs">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="main.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I hope this help those who might get confused with IISnode settings in Plesk. And these settings apply generally to all Node.js applications, they are not limited to NestJs which is just upper level framework on node.js, and particularly much on Express. But error messages in IISNode can sometimes be a bit misleading and it takes some pain to see through them.

NestJs is really awesome and it is great that those who have to, or love to, use IIS can easily deploy super modern NestJs backend apps to IIS-server, thanks to those who implemented IISnode.

Comment: I have one big doubt for the same. Do we have to keep node_modules folder on server or without also my NestJs application will run? because in main.js file(of dist) we get require(@nestjs/core), so when I try to run it, it gives me error of nestjs/core is required. Please help

Comment: Yes, you have to (1) create the node_modules on IIS via Plesk's NPM install command.  Then (2) restart app (node-server) via button privided by Plesk. Then (3) press "Run script" button and give the console command "start:prod" in the command text field .  Note also that Node.js start command for NestJs in package.json -file must be the following:
 "scripts": {
    ...
      "start:prod": "node main", 
    ...
  },

Comment: So is it only with IISNODE(keeping big node_module folder) or all other deployment server also requires the node_modules? because I am using NestJS and it's node modules size in alsmot 200MB.

Comment: Basically node_modules should not be needed on production server because the build can be done (as often is the case) locally and then only compiled files are ftp-copied to the desired server folder. But the Plesk (on IIS system with iisnode) is implemented so that you can also create node_modules there on the production server and the build is taken on production server as well via the commands I gave. So you do not then have to ftp-copy node_modules to the server.  Are you using Plesk to manage your IIS-server?